# Is it necessary to buy a burial plot while still alive?

Tags: halacha, death, funeral-burial-levaya, segulah

Must someone buy a burial plot while still alive? Moreover, is doing so a segula to stay alive or the opposite? The segula can be because he shows he believes in life after death and does not want to be cremated. One must say that people who are burned to death 'al kiddush hashem' recieve a new body, better than the old one. On the other hand there is a thing as 'al tiftach pe'. One shouldnt mention bad things because that can make them happen.

Comment: One could bring a proof from Avrohom who waited till Sarah died before buying one. But one could answer maybe he thought he wasnt going to die like eliyha and chanoch who flew to heaven alive.

Comment: It's definitely a segula to give your children a hassle when you do die.

Comment: Hi expern and welcome to mi yodeya. Thanks for bringing your question here. Adding a little bit more about why you think this would be a segulah might be helpful.

Comment: In addition to @nikmasi's comment, I would suggest that a source for the idea that such a purchase is _obligatory_ would be useful as well. If the ideas in your comment support or explain the question, incorporating them therewith would improve the question.

Comment: @expern: Good question. +0 so far; I wonder if you could please edit the title to include a question mark?

Answer (score 3):

R. Shemuel Eliyahu [wrote here](http://www.kipa.co.il/ask/show/30395-%D7%9E%D7%94-%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%A2%D7%9C%D7%94-%D7%A9%D7%9C-%D7%A8%D7%9B%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%AA-%D7%90%D7%97%D7%95%D7%96%D7%AA-%D7%A7%D7%91%D7%A8-%D7%91%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D):

על קניה מחיים יש לדעת כי אומרים שיש בזה סגולה לחיים ארוכים וטעם הענין הוא בגלל שהצדיקים לא חוששים מהמיתה וכמו שכתוב "בנים אתם לה' אלוקיכם לא תתגודדו ולא תשימו קרחה בין עינכם למת" למדנו שככל שהאם יותר קרוב לאלוקים בבחינת "בנים" פחות הוא חושש מהמיתה. והצדיקים הגדולים מתו באהבה "מיתת נשיקה". וכתוב על זה בגמרא על זאת יתפלל כל חסיד אליך לעת מצוא" שזוהי המיתה כי במיתת האדם הוא מתקן כנגד כל מה שתיקן בכל ימי חייו. כך הקונה חלקת קרקע לקבורה מלמד על כך שאינו חושש מהמיתה כי הוא יודע שיש חיים אחרי המוות, ומראה על אמונתו בתחית המתים.

On the matter of acquiring burial plots for the living, there are those who say that it is a "segulah" for living a long life, and the reason for this is because the righteous do not worry about death, as it is written "Ye are the children of the LORD your God: ye shall not cut yourselves, nor make any baldness between your eyes for the dead." From which we learn that the closer one is to God as denoted by the term "sons" the less one fears death. And the greatest of the righteous die with a loving "death kiss." And the Talmud writes concerning "For this let every one that is godly pray unto Thee in a time when Thou mayest be found" This refers to death, for in death a man corrects all that which he sought to rectify all the days of his life. Thus one who purchases a burial plot demonstrates that he does not fear death for he knows that there is an afer-life and he shows his belief in the resurrection of the dead.

Comment: The link in the answer proves this from avrohom ovinu. I dont know how. Its the opposite he waited till Sarah was dead before buying the plot.

Comment: @expern but he bought his own before he died.

Comment: But since he didnt buy for Sarah or himself previously no proof can be drawn.

Comment: Maybe if Avrohom would have asked for it earlier, Efron would have wondered why he wanted that particular field and got wise to the fact that Adam and Eve where buried there. He then would have sold it to the highest bidder. Whereas now when Sarah had died in the neighborhood  he even offered to give it for free thinking it was a useless piece of ground not realizing its value.

Comment: @expern the material in the link citing Abraham's acquisition of Makhpela attempts to show the importance of being buried in a place connected to one's ancestors... it is only once he begins "ולגבי שאלתך על קניה מחיים etc." that he attempts to support the specific idea of the benefit of acquiring a plot while alive. That is why I only cited that section.

Comment: But he doesnt seem to have any support. He only give a 'private' reason. In the question I have given a reason to say the opposite.

Comment: Also once Sarah was buried there he also wanted to be. And certainly not anyone else be buried there which would have been the case if he hadnt bought it. So no proof at all once Sarah was buried there but the opposite proof still stands that he didnt buy it in advance.

Comment: @expern what do you mean by a "private reason"?

Comment: A reason for which he brings no proof

Comment: The reason he offers for the idea that buying a plot in advance is a segula for long life is: הקונה חלקת קרקע לקבורה מלמד על כך שאינו חושש מהמיתה כי הוא יודע שיש חיים אחרי המוות, ומראה על אמונתו בתחית המתים ... by "proof" do you mean another authority who makes the suggestion? If so, we will end up with a regress going further and further back perpetually asking "and who is he basing that on"... as for your concern of "al tiftah peh" one might suggest that it is only relevant to non-inevitability.

Comment: For the record my interest is academic, I don't buy into all this "segula" stuff.

Comment: This rabbi whom i have not yet heard of is hardly a well known authority. I am expecting someone of a previous generation or one well known today. Otherwise I think I am entitled to also give an opinion. Although it is inevitable, one hastens it by mentioning it. One can hardly buy a burial plot without doing that.

Comment: He's pretty well known in E"Y, and has been in the English Jewish/Israeli media several times to my memory... his statement is the only one I found addressing your question. You don't like it... nu? I never said you aren't entitled to an opinion, I'm glad you have one!

Comment: I am quite sure that such a 'simple' question must have also been thought of earlier than today.

Comment: Not if there are mistaken premises deemed obvious in earlier generations.